# Facebook Pixel Duplication Conversions API with Javascript & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, pixel

I have implemented the Facebook Pixel Events and they are working properly for now. Now I wanted to implement the Facebook Conversions API as well. Therefore I'm using the Facebook Business SDK to trigger the default Conversion Events of Facebook from my Serverside PHP Code. Now: I'm using the automatic events for the Facebook Pixel events.

So my question is, how can I now set the event id of my conversion events from the PHP code to the same event id as the automatic events have? These events are configured using the Event-Setup-Tool offered by Facebook.

Is there any solution to that without using GTM?

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate an event id (any hash) in your back-end and use the same event id in your front-end. Your facebook pixel and conversion api request gotta have the same event id, this way Facebook will be able to deduplicate events.